# Insert data from table into db - SQL Server/VS 2010

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I want to insert the data from a table "Main" with columns Last, First, Zip, and an e-mail address.  If there is an e-mail address, for example, I need to insert the person as a user, with a generated username and password, if not, I'll be adding it as a person.  What's the simplest way with VS 2010(preferably C#)/SQL Server 2008?  Also, I need a method to save the username/password combinations to a local folder.   Thanks!

Sorry for not being clear, I understand the manipulating data walkthrough, but my question is actually more along these lines: I have Joe Brown, with an e-mail address and zip code data, but I have about 10000 of these.  I have them in a table, 
MAIN", within ExampleDB, and ExampleDB has many tables, such as PersonName, PersonAddress, PersonEmail, etc.  I want to be able to insert the data from the OldDB into ExampleDB, doing a foreach on each row.  So table MAIN has many columns, and I need to take the data and insert it into the other table structure.  Thanks!

Comment: Simplest way to?  Insert into a table or something else?  I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Are you using it or are other users as well?

Answer (score 0):

I've got a link for you to an MSDN walkthrough on using the Linq 2 SQL API to modify data in a database.

I recommend you run through the walkthrough and you should have a better set of questions to come search Stack overflow with.

[MSDN Walkthrough: Manipulating Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386927%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)